# Laravel View not Loading

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel, and when I try to return a view in my controller nothing is showing up on the page.

View location: /resources/views/search.blade.php

Content of search.blade.php:

```
@extends( 'layouts.top10' )

@section( 'content' )
    {{ $content }}
@endsection
```

Code in layout does NOT matter because it is working for many many other pages.

Code in controller (If I echo $content from the controller it shows up on the page, but nothin from the view or layout is shown):

```
public function show( $keyword ) {
    $keyword = urldecode( $keyword );
    $keyword_no_slash = str_replace( '-', ' ', $keyword );

    $page = Page::where( 'title', 'like', $keyword_no_slash )->first();
    Self::showPage( $page );
}
public function showPage( $page ) {
    $content = "Test content";
    // If I echo $content here, it is shown on the page
    return view( 'search', compact( 'content' ) );
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get( '/{keyword}', 'SearchController@showPage');
```

There are no errors in my /storage/logs/laravel.log 
There are no errors in my /var/log/apache2/error.log

I have already tried clearing my laravel view cache, and my cloudflare cache (plus it's in Dev mode)-- many times.

And nothing shops up on the page unless I echo it from the controller.

It seems like everything in the view is being completely ignored. I can even put php code that should error out, all I get is a blank screen.

Laravel Framework 5.5.43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning your view all the way out to the app. When your `show()` function is getting called first (presumably by a route we can't see), you are calling `self::showPage()`, but not actually doing anything with the data it is returning (in this case, the view). So the app is running its function, not receiving the data, and continuing all its merry way. Since you are running both functions, you were still able to dump from `showPage()`, but without `show()` continuing to pass the view up the line, it gets lost and you see a blank page.

To correct the problem, simply add a return to pass the data up to the app.

```
public function show( $keyword ) {
    $keyword = urldecode( $keyword );
    $keyword_no_slash = str_replace( '-', ' ', $keyword );

    $page = Page::where( 'title', 'like', $keyword_no_slash )->first();
    return Self::showPage( $page );
}
```